# JQuery dialog display according to html

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

The JQuery  `$('#dialog').html(htmlContent)` displays the html as dialog's body .
I want to display it like twitter bootstrap modal approach .
For ex:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">
          some content...            
</div>
<div class='ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content'>
          some content...           
</div>
```

Now , at time displaying dialog the 'title-bar' div content should be display in dialog's title header and same for diloag body should show 'ui-dialog-content' divs content.
So is there is any way to show dialog with this approach..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you're trying to achieve:

```
$("#dialog").remove(); // Remove any existing dialog
var $html = '<div id="dialog"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">' + headerContent + '</div>' +
'<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">' + htmlContent + '</div></div>';
// Append modal HTML to the page
$("body").append( $html );
```

You'll need to dress it up with some CSS of course.

Comment: Thanks for reply,but its not work for me as i have string of html content from which i'm unable to filtered out title or body content,so i want to set it in that html string so that it renders content as expected.

Comment: You can use `headerContent = $(htmlContent).find("title").html()` to get the title and then remove it from `htmlContent.